# JQuery input form is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two input fields, one for sorting one for the radius.
I want it to work if I set the sortby it should save and resubmit with the order I've selected, and the radis would work the same way, without getting the two input fields messing up each other. Right now whatever I set for radius is go over by the sortby field, even it get posted as a value and displayed under the wrong input.
Someone please look it over and help me to solve this.
Thank you, I would really appreciate any help with this problem.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dropdown Menus</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('ul li').on('click', function() {
     $('input#shortby').val($(this).data('val'));
     $('#order').submit();
     });
    });

   $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('ul li').on('click', function() {
     $('input#radius').val($(this).data('val'));
     $('#order').submit();
     });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
 echo "POST VALUE: ". $_POST['shortby'];
 echo "POST VALUE: ". $_POST['radius'];
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post" id="order">
  <input id="shortby" type="hidden" value="" name="shortby">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
       <div>Sort By: <?php echo $_POST['shortby']; ?>
        <ul>
          <li data-val="Featured"       ><a href="#" >Featured</a></li>
          <li data-val="Name"           ><a href="#" >Name</a></li>
          <li data-val="Price (Highest)"><a href="#" >Price (Highest)</a></li>
          <li data-val="Price (Lowest)" ><a href="#" >Price (Lowest)</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>


  <input id="radius" type="hidden" value="" name="radius">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
       <div>Radius: <?php echo $_POST['radius']; ?>
        <ul>
          <li data-val="10"> <a href="#" >10</a></li>
          <li data-val="20"> <a href="#" >20</a></li>
          <li data-val="30"> <a href="#" >30</a></li>
          <li data-val="40"> <a href="#" >40</a></li>
          <li data-val="50"> <a href="#" >50</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Just fyi: `<?php echo $_POST['shortby']; ?>` and `<?php echo $_POST['radius']; ?>` are vulnerable to Reflected XSS attacks

Comment: Then What would you suggest?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php/130323#130323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the problem is that you are setting the same data, i.e. val in both cases. Check the following

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input#shortby').val(<?php echo (isset($_POST['shortby'])) ? json_encode($_POST['shortby']) : ''; ?>);
    $('input#radius').val(<?php echo (isset($_POST['radius'])) ? json_encode($_POST['radius']) : ''; ?>);
    $('ul li').on('click', function() {
        var shortbyVal, radiusVal;
        if($(this).data('val') === undefined){
            radiusVal = $(this).data('val2');
            shortbyVal = $('input#shortby').val();
        }
        else if($(this).data('val2') === undefined){
            shortbyVal = $(this).data('val');
            radiusVal = $('input#radius').val();
        }$('input#shortby').val(shortbyVal); 
     $('input#radius').val(radiusVal);
     $('#order').submit();
     });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
 echo "POST VALUE: ". $_POST['shortby'];
 echo "POST VALUE: ". $_POST['radius'];
?>

<form action="1.php" method="post" id="order">
  <input id="shortby" type="hidden" value="" name="shortby">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
       <div>Sort By: <?php echo $_POST['shortby']; ?>
        <ul>
          <li data-val="Featured"       ><a href="#" >Featured</a></li>
          <li data-val="Name"           ><a href="#" >Name</a></li>
          <li data-val="Price (Highest)"><a href="#" >Price (Highest)</a></li>
          <li data-val="Price (Lowest)" ><a href="#" >Price (Lowest)</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>


  <input id="radius" type="hidden" value="" name="radius">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
       <div>Radius: <?php echo $_POST['radius']; ?>
        <ul> <!-- Observe the change in data-val to data-val2 -->
          <li data-val2="10"> <a href="#" >10</a></li>
          <li data-val2="20"> <a href="#" >20</a></li>
          <li data-val2="30"> <a href="#" >30</a></li>
          <li data-val2="40"> <a href="#" >40</a></li>
          <li data-val2="50"> <a href="#" >50</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

This should be a good workaround for that

Comment: I have modified it, but something is still wrong. First input works fine, but the second doesn't change itself, and on submit it clears the value for the first input.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that you are calling for POST variables. When you click one of the shortby, POST['shortby'] is set. When you click one of radius, POST['radius'] is set. To fix this, it would be better if you sent the value of input#radius or input#shortby separately in each document.ready

Comment: So How would that look like? Can you modify it ?

Comment: Edit: Actually, you are resetting the value of input#shortby or input#radius each time the page loads to "".

Comment: Well than I would add value="<?php echo $_POST['shortby']; ?>" and value="<?php echo $_POST['radius']; ?>" would solve that. but radius is still not posting on submit.

Comment: Try the above version now.